# How can I insert data one table and update some data in another table in asp.net mvc 5 & Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework for my stationery project. my entity models are (I have given the important fields only).

```
public partial class Purchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }       
    public string ChallanNo { get; set; }
    public string BillNo { get; set; }     
}
public partial class Stock
{
    public int MatId { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SystemDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now the requirement is when I create the purchase order it will insert data to Purchase table. Now I have to update the Stock table for Quantity field automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the stock table while saving the purchase. Assume that the purchases you want to save is in object model

```
using (var context=new SomeDBContext()){
  context.Purchases.Add(model);
  var itemRow=context.Stocks.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.item==model.item);
  if (itemRow !=null)
  {
     itemRow.Quantity+ =model.Quantity;
     context.Entry(itemRow).State=EntityState.Modified;
  }
  else
  {
     context.Stocks.Add(new stock(){Item=model.Item,Quantity=model.Quantity,.......});
  }
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note:

1. You need to implement another code for update and delete of purchases
2. The best method is to plan your table so that there will be a master detail relationship between stock and purchases so that you can update the stock quantity with the sum of all purchases under its detail. That way, you can update the stock (master) from within the purchase Quantity property setter when the quantity changes